# YML file properties in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I am using YAML file in configratuion of my Spring Boot app.

```
api:
  version: 2.0.2
spring:
    profiles:
        active: dev
    devtools:
        restart:
            enabled: true
        livereload:
            enabled: false 

server:
    port: 8080
    compression:
        enabled: true
        mime-types: text/html,text/css,application/javascript,application/json
```

Can someone explain me why the `api version` is there for? When I remove it I have an error while start my app.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: headerValues cannot contain null values
```

Is there any easy going website where I can find keys and values of parameters which should be placed in a yaml file?

Is it possible the set the version of artifact in yaml file instead of pom.xml?

Comment: Provide a minimal example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do a search in the project code for "api.version", maybe it is injected somewhere as a `@Value`.

Comment: @Gimby Not really